# MySQLdb mutilating data

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using MySQLdb to get data from a database.

I cannot properly read some of the data. The data is UUIDs such as 5ec25298899d4d85896e5718bd6e6431

Code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="******", user="********", passwd="********", db="******")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM bm_player_bans ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1")
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        mostRecentBanUUID = row[1]
    print results
    print mostRecentBanUUID
```

[Here's the strange output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpeYX.png)

The first line is the result of **print results**.
The second line is the result of **print mostRecentBanUUID**. The expected result of the second line was **5ec25298899d4d85896e5718bd6e6431**.

My question is, is there a way to get these strings from the database without mutilating them?

Sorry if this doesn't make too much sense, I'm writing this at 1:30am after fiddling with this for hours. As such, if you have any questions about the issue, please feel free to ask. :-)

Comment: The data is wrong in the database. If you go into your MySQL shell and do `SELECT * FROM bm_player_bans WHERE id=149` you will see the same result.

Comment: The encoding looks wrong